# How to properly unset a class property in PHP during runtime?

Tags: php, object, runtime, unset

I'm having a class that has a property which I want to unset/destroy during runtime. The unsetting happens in a specific method, but the method that calls it returns `TRUE` in `property_exists`, while it can't directly access the property with `$this->property` as it returns a notice `Notice: Undefined property:...`

```php
  public function get(int $id) {
    if ($record->data) {
      $this->_transform($record); //  Calling method that unsets prop
    }    

    if (! property_exists($this, 'isEmpty') ) { //  FALSE
      $this->transform();
    }else{
      echo $this->isEmpty; //  FALSE as well!
    }

    return $this;
  }

  private method _transform(Record $record) {
    unset($this->isEmpty); //  Unsetting happens here

    return;
  }
```

As you can see in the code after the unsetting, the `property_exists` returns TRUE which shouldn't happen, but the property is undefined.

***EDIT***

It seems that if the property is declared in class' schema then it cannot be destroyed/unset (see selected answer's demo) and in fact it behaves paradoxically: property_exists => TRUE, object->property => warning

BUT when the property is not defined but created at object's construction, then it can be unset and behave as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as of PHP 5.3.0 that if you define it as an object variable then `property_exists` returns `true` even after `unset`. Use `isset($this->isEmpty)` instead as this returns `false` after `unset`.

See the differences: [**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/kBBBd)

However, you should probably take a different approach like setting to `true` or `false` or `null` or something and checking that.

Demo Code:

```php
<?php

class test {

    public function a(){
        $this->isEmpty = 1;
        var_dump(property_exists($this, 'isEmpty'));
        unset($this->isEmpty);
        var_dump(property_exists($this, 'isEmpty'));
    }
}
$t = new test();
$t->a();

class test2 {
    public $isEmpty;
    
    public function a(){
        $this->isEmpty = 1;
        var_dump(property_exists($this, 'isEmpty'));
        unset($this->isEmpty);
        var_dump(property_exists($this, 'isEmpty'));
    }
}
$t = new test2();
$t->a();

class test3 {
    public $isEmpty;
    
    public function a(){
        $this->isEmpty = 1;
        var_dump(isset($this->isEmpty));
        unset($this->isEmpty);
        var_dump(isset($this->isEmpty));
    }
}
$t = new test3();
$t->a();
```

Comment: Yes the problem is that property_exists returns TRUE while the direct access returns a warning, which is paradoxical. One solution would be to go for a different approach and another one, I just found regarding your examples, would be to not define the property in class but rather create it during runtime, where it behaves as expected.

Comment: if you want extend your answer by saying that it can be achieved if the property is defined after the object construction as per your #1 example in your demo. Thanks

Comment: I added the demo code to the answer in case the link ever breaks. If you disagree, please just remove it, no biggie.