# How to remove property from object in PHP 7.4+

Tags: php, php-7.4, php-8

How to remove property if property has type.

**unset()** working if property does not have type.

```
class A
{
  public string $a;
  public $b;
}

$o = new A();
unset($o->a);
unset($o->b);

// object(A)#1 (0) {
//   ["a"]=>
//   uninitialized(string)
// }
```

Comment: What is the effect you're actually trying to achieve (I'm assuming you don't _actually_ care what var_dump outputs)? Removing a declared property is a somewhat unusual thing to do, but the "initialized" state has been defined such that certain tricks involving it still work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to properly unset a class property in PHP during runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55615108/how-to-properly-unset-a-class-property-in-php-during-runtime)

Comment: @0stone0, that one doesn't specifically address typed properties, at least as far as I can tell

Comment: The property isn't exported with `var_export`, `serialize` or `json_encode` (the output shown is `var_dump`). I don't see the issue with this behavior (it is a declared class property). Is there another reason this may be unwanted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [RFC on typed properties](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/typed_properties_v2):

> If a typed property is unset(), then it returns to the uninitialized state. While we would love to remove support for the unsetting of properties, this functionality is currently used for lazy initialization by Doctrine, in combination with the functionality described in the following section.